# String index out of range: 4

Tags: java

I am a beginner here to Java. So I tried to run this code here, but it kept giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4.
```

I need some help. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestFour
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{

  String inp= new String();
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Word ");
  inp = scan.nextLine();
  int output = 1;
  int [] board = new int[40];
  int points = 0; 
  int totalpoints = 0;
  int input;
  //start of for loop
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
     input = scan.nextInt();
     for (int j = 0; j < inp.length(); j++)
     {
        //values of letters
        if(inp.charAt(i) == 'a' || inp.charAt(i) == 'e')
        {
           points = 1;
        }
        else if(inp.charAt(i) == 'd' || inp.charAt(i) == 'r') 
        {
           points = 2;
        }
        else if(inp.charAt(i) == 'b' || inp.charAt(i) == 'm')
        {
           points = 3;
        }
        else if(inp.charAt(i) == 'v' || inp.charAt(i) == 'y')
        {
           points = 4;
        }
        else if(inp.charAt(i) == 'j' || inp.charAt(i) == 'x')
        {
           points = 8;
        }
        else
        {
           points = points; 
        }
        //checking if double letter or triple letter and executing program
        if ( input % 3 == 0 && input % 6 != 0)
        {
           points = points * 2;
        }
        else
        {
           points = points;

        }   
        if (input % 5 == 0 && input != 15)
        {
           points = points * 3;
        }
        else 
        {
           points = points;
        }
        totalpoints = totalpoints + points;
        input = input + 1;
     }//end of for loop
     input = input - 4;
     //checking if double word or triple word and executing program
     for (int k = 0; k < inp.length(); k++)
     {   
        if (input % 7 == 0 && input != 21 && input != 25)
        {
           totalpoints = totalpoints * 2;
        }
        else
        {
           totalpoints = totalpoints;
        }

        if (input % 8 == 0 && input != 40)
        {
           totalpoints = totalpoints * 3;
        }
        else
        {
           totalpoints = totalpoints;
        }
        input = input + 1;
     }
  }
  System.out.println(totalpoints);
}
}
```

The problem starts at the for loop the fifth time I enter the input. Thank you for your time. I really don't get how to fix it even though I know what is going on.

Comment: Post (add to your question) the complete exception, including stack trace.

Comment: Yeah, the exception stack trace will tell you what line you failed on.  But it's almost certainly the first `charAt` you do.  (Hint:  Use `System.out.println` to print values in your program, to see what it's doing.)

Comment: Your `i` loop is checking from 0 to 4, which means first five letters of a word and it's crashing on the fifth letter. Are you sure you're not just supplying `inp` with a four letter word and thus causing the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong iteration counter, replace `inp.charAt(i)` with `inp.charAt(j)`.

Comment: that didn't help. The problem is that there has to be four letters put into the inp, and five inputs into the input.

Comment: @user3133350 - Then perhaps you'd grace us with the stack trace.  (Udo's right, by the way.  There are probably other bugs, but definitely that one.)

Comment: @user3133350, then what is `j` for?

Comment: sorry it is just that I needed to change that and a couple of little bugs, thank you